# R - call function with variable argument in loop

Tags: r, arguments, call

How can I use function call in a for loop where one variable is the current iteration of the loop? My current code (very simplified) looks like this:

```
funCall <- call('FUN', arg1 = 10, arg2 = get('i'))
for(i in 1:x){
  ans[i] <- eval(funCall)
}
```

Given a FUN like `arg1 * arg2` the evaluated function should return 10 for i = 1, 20 for i = 2 etc.
Using `get('i')` I get the error that object 'i' is not found and I don't understand 

1) why`get` is evaluated right away inside `call`

2) how I can implement this `call`to get the correct `i`

*edit*

The solution to the problem is to use another `call()` inside the `call` like
`call('FUN', arg1 = 10, arg2 = call('get','i'))` so the `get()`function is only evaluated inside the loop.

Comment: Move `funCall <- call('FUN', arg1 = 10, arg2 = get(i))` inside the for loop? I mean, you can't reference `i` before it is created.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Can you give some context? There's likely a better way to go about whatever you're doing...

Comment: On the first pass of the loop, `i` is `1`, so `get(i)` will error with `invalid first argument`. What do you *think* is happening here? (I agree with @Gregor, there is something else going on here.)

Comment: And why `get`? `get` expects a character string as its first arg. `get("i")` seems closer in spirit (though still doesn't work). Seems like a functional might be a better approach...

Comment: This code snippet is just part of a more complex function.  @joran the function that should be used inside the loop depends on the inputs of the other function and the idea was to avoid an `if` statment inside the function